# How to get notification and save it in text file for android 4.0 +?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to save all notification in one text file.

First I have tried it by `NotificationListenerService` but it's just for android 4.3+

I want that my service, support android 4.0+

Then I tried it by `AccessibilityService` and I did not succeed again

Would you give me some example code?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

Best route is go through this simple doc and example

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

This should give you all the details required.

When you receive notification.. saving message to text using any android technique.